# decent ASP.NET / SQL tutorial?

Tags: asp.net, sql

I've never used databases before in my work.  I know some basic SQL syntax.  Just looking for a decent tutorial that will show me how to set up a database and use it to serve information on an ASP.NET page.

Answer (score 2):

[How do I Create Data-Driven Web Sites?](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-create-data-driven-web-sites) and other tutorials from [asp.net](http://www.asp.net/get-started/).

Answer (score 1):

You might benefit from some of the video tutorials from:

http://www.learnvisualstudio.net

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tutorial on several subjects of data access in ASP.NET:

http://www.asp.net/Learn/data-access/

Answer (score 0):

I found the [4guysfromrolla](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202742/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com) tutorials pretty useful when I was in the same situation although they might be a bit outdated now.

Maybe try check out [this one](https://web.archive.org/web/20210802161558/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/110905-1.aspx) in particular